# matplotlib pyplot: subplot size

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I plot a single graph as below, it will be of size (x * y).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

However, if I plot 3 sub-graphs in the same row, each of them will be of size ((x / 3) * y).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey = True)
for i in range(3):
    ax[i].plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

How can I obtain these 3 subplots, each of which is of size (x * y)?

Comment: You could make the figure size ((3*x)*y).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking if there's a way to specify that i'd like to retain its original size, instead of specifying the size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The figure object has a default size that does not know about the number of subplots.  You can change the figure size when you make the figure to suit your needs though.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx = 3
ny = 1

dxs = 8.0
dys = 6.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ny, nx, sharey = True, figsize=(dxs*nx, dys*ny) )
for i in range(nx):
    ax[i].plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
```