# How you can define the dimensions of a subplot (in inches) within a figure with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My figure has dimensions of figsize=(10,10) and one subplot within it. How can i define the dimension of the subplot to be 8 inches W x 8 inches H regardles the data range the subplot it shows?

**EDIT:** The reason I am searching for this is that I am trying to create some plots for publication. So I need my plots to have a fixed width and height to be able to be inserted to the manuscrpipt seamsly.

Here's the striped down code:

```
map_size = [8,8]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=map_size)
ax.plot(data)
fig.savefig('img.png', dpi=300,)  # figure is the desired size, subplot seems to be scaled to fit to fig
```

Comment: if the subplot in your figure occupies (80, 80)% of the width and height respectively, is that what you're going for? Or do you want the subplot to occupy 8 inches width and height regardless of the figure size?

Comment: Regardless of the figure size I want if possible the subplot to have a constant size. Of Course the figure is bigger from the subplot to accomodate any labels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811059/matplotlib-pyplot-subplot-size#24811670

Comment: @user528025 One option is to define the subplot as a standalone figure and set its size in inches, then insert as a subplot inside the 'master' figure. [How do I include a matplotlib Figure object as subplot?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754215/2466336)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `fig.subplots_adjust` to set the size of the subplot within the figure. The arguments `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` are fractional units (of the total figure dimensions). So, for an 8x8 subplot in a 10x10 figure, `right - left = 0.8`, etc.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10.,10.))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1,right=0.9,bottom=0.1,top=0.9)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Doing it like this, you would have to manually change the left, right, bottom and top values if you change the figure size.

I guess you could build that calculation into your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

subplotsize=[8.,8.]
figuresize=[10.,10.]   

left = 0.5*(1.-subplotsize[0]/figuresize[0])
right = 1.-left
bottom = 0.5*(1.-subplotsize[1]/figuresize[1])
top = 1.-bottom

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(figuresize[0],figuresize[1]))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=left,right=right,bottom=bottom,top=top)

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Comment: what units are left,right,bottom and top in subplots_adjust method?

Comment: @user528025: They're fractional units (of the total figure dimensions)

Comment: Yep, as @FredL pointed out, they are fractional units of the figure. I've edited the answer to clarify that

Comment: does hspace or wspace parameters have any effect if there is only one subplot?

Comment: no, they define the spaces (`hspace` = height, `wspace` = width) between two or more subplots